# Having problem with controlled form validation in Reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, controlled-component

Hi i'm newbie learning to code and start with Js, Reactjs. I convert my code from class component to functional component and then my validation stop working. i have looking around but yet to find answer, can someone help? ^^"

```js
export default function AddComment() {
    const [formValue, setFormValue] = useState ({
        rating: '5',
        yourname: '',
        comment: '',
    })
    const {rating, yourname, comment} = formValue
    const [isModalOpen, setIsModalOpen] = useState(false)
    const [touched, setTouched] = useState({yourname: false})
        
    const handleInputChange = (event) => {
        const {name, value} = event.target
        setFormValue((prevState) => {
            return {
                prevState,
                [name]:value,
            };}) 
    }
   
    const handleBlur = (field) => (evt) => {
        setTouched({
            touch: {...touched, [field]: true }
        })
    };
    function validate(yourname) {
        const errors = {
            yourname: ''
        };
        if (touched.yourname && yourname.length <2)
            errors.yourname = 'Your name should be atleast 2 characters';
        else if (touched.yourname && yourname.length >= 10)
            errors.yourname = 'Your name should be less than 10 characters';
        return errors    

    }

    const errors = validate(yourname)
        return (
            <ModalBody>
            <Form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
               <FormGroup row>
                   <Label htmlFor='yourname' md = {12}>Your Name</Label>
                   <Col md = {12}>
                     <Input type= 'text' id= 'yourname' name= 'yourname' value= {yourname} 
                     valid={errors.yourname === ''} invalid= {errors.yourname !== ''} 
                     onBlur= {handleBlur('yourname')} onChange= {handleInputChange}/>
                     <FormFeedback>{errors.yourname}</FormFeedback>
                   </Col>
               </FormGroup>
             </Form>
            </ModalBody>
        )
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure this will solve your problem, but notice on `handleInputChange` you are not spreading the previous state, so the object you're setting state with looks like:

```
{
  prevState: {...the actual previous state},
  [name]: ...what you wanted to change
}
```